# Unclustering still showing clustered markers Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using android maps utils for clustering the markers on google maps api v2. It worked fine, but when I go to max zoom then clusters becomes un-clustered which not showing markers pin but clustered markers/circles.

Here is the code:

```
        binding.mapView!!.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback { mMap ->
           googleMap = mMap
            // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
            // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)

            // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
            // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)


            // For showing a move to my location button
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) !== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) !== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return@OnMapReadyCallback
            }
           googleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

setUpMap()

        })
 

fun setUpMap(){
        var latLng1 = position()
        val offsetItem = MyItem(latLng1?.latitude!!, latLng1?.longitude!!)


     
        var latLng2 = position()
        val offsetItem1 = MyItem(latLng2?.latitude!!, latLng2?.longitude!!)
    


        mClusterManager = ClusterManager(this, googleMap)
        var renderer = MarkerClusterRenderer(this, googleMap, mClusterManager!!)
        mClusterManager!!.renderer = renderer


       googleMap?.setOnCameraMoveListener(renderer)
        googleMap?.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager)

        mClusterManager?.addItem(offsetItem)
        mClusterManager?.addItem(offsetItem1)
        mClusterManager?.cluster()

}

  open class MarkerClusterRenderer(
        context: Context?, map: GoogleMap?,
        clusterManager: ClusterManager<MyItem?>
    ) :
        DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem?>(context, map, clusterManager),
        ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener {

        var ctx: Context? = context
        var mapIn: GoogleMap? = map
        override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<MyItem?>): Boolean {
            return zoomValue!! < 13
        }

        override fun onClusterItemClick(item: MyItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: MyItem, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) { // 5
            markerOptions.icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                    getMarkerBitmapFromView(
                    )
                )
            )
        }

        override fun onCameraMove() {
           mClusterManager?.cluster()
           zoomValue = mapIn?.cameraPosition?.zoom!!
        }
    }
```

Image:
**1- Clustered: Zoom Level**
[image: Clustered: Zoom Level 2]

**2- Unclustered: Zoom level above 13**
[image: Unclustered: Zoom level above 13]